# Interpret convolution diagram

Tags: signal-processing, convolution

How do I interpret this "do convolutions" diagram?

1) How are the results computed?

2) When looking at this part: "x[n-k]" Do you interpret convolutions as delays or time reversals?

$ y[n]= \sum_{k=0}^{M} h[k]x[n-k] = h[n]*x[n]$

$ h[n] =  \delta[x] - \delta[n-1] + 2\delta[n-2] - \delta[n-3]+ \delta[n-4] $

[image]

Comment: Convolution you can interpret as first reversing $x$ in time i.e. $x[n-k]$ and then computing cross correlation.

Comment: @oldrinb Or as echos: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/6355

Answer (score 0):

1. Convolutions are computed by adding up the values of $h[k]x[n-k]$, which makes sense following the formula $$h*x=\sum_{k=0}^nh[k]x[n-k]$$ Along these lines, note that each entry for $y[n]$ is the sum of the entries above (not including the top two rows).
2. <s>$x[n-k]$ is a time delay, not a time reversal (which would be something along the lines $x[-n]$).</s> If you think of $x[n-k]$ as a function of $k$, then $x$ is first time reversed, then shifted forward by $n$.

Comment: Why is h[0]x[n] equal to 0 and not 1?

Comment: That depends on the value of $n$, which changes depending on which column you're looking at.  With $n=-1$ (the first column), we have $$h[0]x[n]=h[0]x[-1]=1\times0=0$$ With $n=0$ (the second column), we have $$h[0]x[n]=h[0]x[0]=1\times1=1$$

Comment: Notations confuse me a bit... Then why do we notate '0' for h[1]x[-1-1] = h[1]x[-2] instead of undefined?

Comment: Because $x[-2]$ is defined.  It's defined to be $0$. Both $x$ and $h$ are zero on all values to the left of this table.  That is, $h[n]=x[n]=0$ for $n\leq -1$.